# Spring Security in a Multi module Maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-security, structure, multi-module

I want to use spring security in my project but I don't know where I put my new classes, this is my dependency tree:
**controller** depends on **service**
**service** depends on **infrastructure**
and my Project structure looks like that :

```
loyalty-service (Root)
|-- controller
|   |-- UserController.java
|   |-- ...
|
|-- service
|   |-- UserService.java
|   |-- ...
|
|-- infrastructure
|   |-- Repository.java
|   |-- ...
|
|-- ...
|
|-- pom.xml
|--
```

Comment: It is mostly opinion based. For example, it is possible to put them in a "configuration" package or in a "security" package.

Comment: so, i don't need to create a new package ?

Comment: You can organize the packages as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What is you provide is not multi module project, this is one project with several packages. Anyway, you can create another package - "configuration", "security" etc. name it as you wish, and put your spring security configuration files there

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's a multi-module project, and each module has its own POM.